# Sitecore 8.2 does not officially support Windows Server 2016 but is it compatible in reality and will it work in production

Tags: scaling, solution-architecture, infrastructure

I'm updating my server architecture at an awkward time. I want to get Windows Server 2016 so I can support HTTP/2 but I'm currently running Sitecore 8.2 which doesn't officially support Windows Server 2016 (and therefore HTTP/2).

Sitecore 8.3 is about to be released which *does* support Windows Server 2016. I plan to upgrade to this, but it seems a shame to get a new server with Windows Server 2012 R2 (just to accommodate Sitecore's official requirements for 8.2) for a short period only to then upgrade to Windows Server 2016 when 8.3 is released.

So I'm planning to run Sitecore 8.2 on Windows Server 2016 in the interim period. I'm aware that my solution will not be supported by Sitecore Tech Support. My questions are:

- **Is there any actual reason why Sitecore won't run on Windows Server 2016 or is it just that Sitecore haven't fully tested it?**
- **Are there any caveats I may not have thought of?**
- **Does anyone have any experience of running a production Sitecore instance on Windows Server 2016?**

Comment: Is not fully tested on that Windows Server 2016

Comment: @SitecoreClimber thanks for the comment - any elaboration on my other questions?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have. Normally when they test on a new version of OS they don't have big surprises.

Answer (score 8):

It comes down to support.

Is there a known reason Sitecore wouldn't work on 2016?  No.  It will run on 2016 and in all likelihood there will not be any major issues in doing so.

But if there is; this is what it comes down to. Let's say you ran into an issue and Sitecore Support was not able to help you out due to it being rooted in something around Server 2016 - *you would be on your own* then. At the very least from a legal perspective; so no suing Sitecore over stuff that doesn't work on a platform they already told you they do not support yet.

So this is the caveat. You're looking at a compatibility table of Sitecore and Server versions that Sitecore officially *support*.  That you can, in all likelihood, make it run on platforms outside the realm of support is fine. Just be aware of the shift in liability.

That said; I've heard of several people saying they run Sitecore on Server 2016 in production environments. Keeping the above in mind; I'd say you'll probably be fine doing it too.

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore 8.2 Update 3 does support Windows Server 2016.

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164

In the operation systems table, Windows Server 2016 is checked under 8.2 and links to the following note: "[21] Compatible beginning with Sitecore XP 8.2 Update-3."

Comment: WTF? That has literally updated in the last 24 hours. Hence why it's [21] and last on the list! And also:

> LAST UPDATED:
August 17, 2017